# How to make a function when any of the given buttons are clicked?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function which runs when any of the given number of buttons are clicked. For example, suppose I have 4 buttons with IDs "one","two","three","four".

The function should run whenever I click the "one" or "two" buttons.
Can it be done without writing an onclick function for each button?

Comment: Post the code you're written in your question please

Comment: Any code to show up your efforts or research ?

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate event and use multiple selectors

```
$(document).on('click', '#one, #two', function (e) {
    // your stuff goes here
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery then you can do something

```
['#one', '#two'].forEach(function(id){
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){ // your code }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately `jQuery` is not tagged mate!

Comment: @Rayon there is a possibility that Manan just doesn't know about jQuery yet.

Comment: @Zohaib I wanted in javascript only

Comment: @MananPachchigar I've updated my answer.. I hope it will work

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Thanks

Comment: @MananPachchigar But you should try jQuery as it is such a beautiful framework and makes writing Javascript soooo much easier.

Comment: @timmyRs I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: `getElementById('#one')` won't work at all.

Comment: @timmyRS, We have comments section to sort out all the possibilities and doubts...